In Scotland, when can police retain key legal documents of a suspect after an arrest?
Can the police hold and refuse to give back a legal document after arrest that would allow a citizen to claim asylum in another state even though their life is likely to be put in danger?

Is this person a citizen of Scotland? If so, why would their life be likely to be put in danger making it necessary for that person to seek asylum in another country?

I find the question difficult to parse/understand. The scenario seems to be: a person is arrested (for what?); the person is a British(?) citizen; for some reason the person might want to claim asylum outside of the UK; the police seized a "legal document" (what kind of legal document? Passport, travel document, ID?) they refuse to return (is the person still under investigation?); for some reason the success of the asylum claim would hinge on the legal document (this would make sense for passport etc, although fleeing the UK doesn't have an obvious reason).

The UK would insist that, despite all they are doing to deter refugees and other migrants, they are meeting the minimum requirements of international humanitarian law. So nobody has their life put in danger by staying in the UK. The accuracy of this claim is hotly debated, and out of scope here. What matters is that UK laws assume that the UK legal system follows international norms.
So what is left is the question if the Scots police can hold on to documents they have seized even after an arrested person is released. The answer to that is yes, generally. If you think the police acted inappropriately in a specific case, either talk to a lawyer or make a complaint.
